# javascript gapi oauth2 causing 401 error

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-api-js-client

I have client side javascript code that needs to be able to load the gmail API and send emails on behalf of the user. I have created my oAuth credentials on the Developer Console, and enabled the gmail API. I have added localhost with the port number I am using to the authorized javascript origins in the console as well. When I run `gapi.client.init`, the `GET` request that `gapi` sends to a google URL returns a `401` error. Why am I getting this error? Here's the code that attempts to load the `gmail.send` scope once the google js API is loaded and calls `handleClientLoad`. The 401 error displays in the console; it is not caught by the asynchronous error handler:

```
function checkAuth() {
    gapi.client.init({
        clientId: '<MY CLIENT ID FROM THE DEV CONSOLE>',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
    }).then(function() {
        gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', function() {});
    }, function(err) {
        alert("There was an error" + err);
    });
}

function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', checkAuth);
}
```

I had everything working just fine until I accidentally deleted the project I was using the Developer Console and had to create a new one. But I don't know of anything different I would have to do besides enabling the gmail API, setting my origin URL, and updating my client ID to match the new project. Previously, I was using an API key, but to my knowledge that is redundant, and even creating/providing a new API key I get the same 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting my request headers, I noticed that the `client_id` did not match. Turns out I still had the old client ID in a call to `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js` used in another part of my html template to check google sign in!